# Define each set requested by listing the elements.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

a) Give a set A with cardinality of 2. So I put A = {1,2}. easy enough 
 
b) Construct a set B so that both of the following statements are true:
A $\in$ B and
A $\subseteq$ B

I was just gonna write B = {1,2} ,but it says A must be an element of B. So I changed it to 
 B = {A, 1, 2}. Did I misinterpret the question or is this correct?

Comment: No, you did not. Maybe to be more explicit, you could write $B=\{\{1,2\},1,2\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Is correct. You can build the set as you want.
Maybe you want to read this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification